# Swift json parsing error: Could not cast value of type NSCFConstantString to NSArray

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have some problems with parsing json using swift code.

**json example**

```
{"responce": "ok","orders": [{"id":"1"), {"id":"2"}, {"id":"3"} ]}
```

and this code working fine

```
let dataArray: NSArray = jsonResult["orders"] as! NSArray
```

but if I get `{"responce": "ok","orders": ""}` I got the `error: Could not cast value of type __NSCFConstantString (0x10c7bfc78) to NSArray (0x10c7c0470).`

Can I somehow check if value is array or not to do not crashed?

Comment: Are you using SwiftyJSON?

Comment: I think yes, if NSJSONSerialization is part of SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can check if the value is a NSArray by doing this:

```
if let dataArray = jsonResult["orders"] as? NSArray {

}
```

If the result of `jsonResult["orders"]` is a NSArray then dataArray will be set and you will go into the if statement.

Comment: I suspect that you can cast it directly to a Swift Array by changing it to `if let dataArray = jsonResult["orders"] as? Array<String>` (provided that it will only store `Strings` otherwise `Array<AnyObject>`)

Comment: +1, but I think you mean `if let orders = jsonResult["orders"] as? [[String: String]] { ... }` or something like that. It's an array of dictionaries, not an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely caused by the response you are getting back from what I assume is a server not being JSON, but being something like an HTML/XML response saying that the server either could not be reached, or that your query/post request was invalid (hence the fact that the value was an "NSCFConstantString").

Using James' answer is a perfectly good way to check that the value is an Array, but you might want to test your requests using a program like Postman to see what he response is, and then hard code a way to handle that error on the user side.

Comment: You're right that he should make sure the response was valid JSON or not, but one does this when one does the JSON parsing, not here, where he's grabbing the `"orders"` value out of a previously parsed JSON object.